# Error when convert float to datatime

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this command that is being called each second in background mode, Every time he is called I add +1 to my variable of type float, and convert to date format:

```
xis = (xis + 1) / 000001;

    //The Format which you want as output
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormat.dateFormat = @"ss:mm:hh";
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    //The Format in which your dateTime currently is
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormat1.dateFormat = @"hh.mm";
    [dateFormat1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];


    NSString *timeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",xis];
    NSDate *dates = [dateFormat1 dateFromString:timeStr];
    NSLog(@"Time: %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:dates]);

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

        recordTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:dates]];

    }];
```

But this code has a problem when the time comes 00:00:12, something goes wrong and the time is the value (null), which may be causing this and how can I solve?

Comment: Why is your first formatter `ss:mm:hh`? That's backwards: It should be `hh:mm:ss` (or `HH:mm:ss`), right? And that's why it would stop at `12`, because `hh` only goes from `01`-`12`. But stepping back, can you describe what you're trying to do? This is a very curious routine and if you describe what you're trying to do, I'm suspect we'll be able to suggest a better approach...

Comment: A few problems: 1. dividing by `000001` does not accomplish anything. 2. "hh" for the hour is for twelve hour time so the number is limited to 12. 3. Consider using an int instead of a float. 4. Consider using `NSDateComponents`. 5. As @Rob states: tell more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Zaph The results what I want is, 00:00:01, 00:00:02... 00:00:13....0:01:00...

Comment: @Rob If i put hh:mm:ss instead of ss:mm:hh, the countdown go to 01:00:00 and stops in 11:00:00

Comment: This makes no sense: `xis = (xis + 1) / 000001;`

Comment: Use `dateWithTimeInterval` or `dateByAddingTimeInterval`.

Comment: (And how do you expect to get a value incrementing in seconds when you're reading hours and minutes from your float?)

Comment: And note what others have said several times -- when you use "hh" that means a 12-hour clock, so 12:59:59 is the largest time you can represent.  "HH" is for 24-hour time.

Comment: (Your code is really screwed up.  You're presenting seconds:minutes:hours, and since you specify "hh" for hours, the 00:00:12 is the highest you can go.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. I would advise against using the `NSTimer` routine to keep track of elapsed time yourself. Timers may not be called with the frequency you expect. Also, if the user suspended the app and came back to it, you don't really want to try to keep this timer going while the app is no longer in the foreground. In short, you want to decouple the updating of the UI from the calculation of the elapsed time string representation.

   So, instead, one should capture the "start time" and then have the routine get the current time, compare that to the "start time" and calculates the string representation of this elapsed time. But notably, there is no incrementing of variables for seconds elapsed, but rather one should rely on the system time of the device.
2. Your formatting problem stems from the awkward conversion of your numeric counter to a date string. The problem was complicated by the fact that the formatting string that was backwards, `ss:mm:hh`.

   First (and to my above point), I'd probably calculate the time elapsed in seconds, by capturing the start time up front and store it in a `CFAbsoluteTime` property:

   ```
   self.start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
   ```

   And, if you really wanted to use `NSDateFormatter`, instead of using it to interpret a numeric value, I would only use it for converting to and from `NSDate` objects. You could, for example, get the `NSDate` for `00:00:00`, use `dateByAddingTimeInterval` to add the elapsed time to the date, and then use the formatter to get the output string:

   ```
   // calculate the time elapsed in seconds

   CFTimeInterval elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.start;

   NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   formatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";

   NSDate *start = [formatter dateFromString:@"00:00:00"];
   NSDate *end = [start dateByAddingTimeInterval:elapsed];
   NSString *elapsedString = [formatter stringFromDate:end];
   ```

   Having said that, I'd probably favor a couple of different approaches. One is to just calculate hours, minutes, and seconds manually:

   ```
   // calculate the time elapsed in seconds

   CFTimeInterval elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.start;

   // convert this to hours, minutes, and seconds

   double seconds;
   double minutes;
   double hours;

   seconds = modf(elapsed / 60.0, &minutes) * 60.0;
   minutes = modf(minutes / 60.0, &hours) * 60.0;

   // create format string

   NSString *elapsedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.0f:%02.0f:%04.1f", hours, minutes, seconds];
   ```

   Or a completely different approach would be to use `NSCalendar`. In this scenario, one might have a `NSDate` property that you initialize with the start time:

   ```
   self.startDate = [NSDate date];
   ```

   And then you could do something like:

   ```
   NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

   NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

   NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:self.startDate toDate:now options:0];

   NSString *elapsedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", (long)components.hour, (long)components.minute, (long)components.second];
   ```

Just a few approaches. But I'd advise against manually incrementing your counter manually, and I might suggest one of these latter techniques.

Comment: I just Want to say thank you, I would tell you that you also just answer a future question that would do in this case I would have to run a NSTimer in background and when a certain time comes the push notification would alert me, but now I know the best practices to make this kind of thing, thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent. Not to split hairs, but if you want the user to be notified at a given time if the app isn't running, you'd use a "local notification", not a "push notification". See [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide: About Location Notifications and Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1).